# how to isolate categorical area of webscrape?

Tags: python, web-scraping, terminal, scrapy

new to webscraping, Im using scrapy and python to grab all the categories from a specific website. The web source is included ([picture of web source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmQ9r.png)), and the code I've been trying is below. I am trying to isolate the categories, which fall after href="/categories#" for each of the items in the class "dropdown-submenu". I've tried
`category_urls = response.css("categories").xpath("@href").extract()`

`category_urls = response.css(".link-list-columns").xpath("@href").extract()`

but I keep getting empty columns.

any help provided is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any elements called "categories" and no class named "link-list-columns", so I'm not sure if the image is really the page you are scraping. (By the way, next time please don't post an image, either link the page or copy and paste the code in the question)

Assuming the print is correct, you could try:

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="dropdown-submenu"]/a/@href').getall()
```

Or the css equivalent

```
response.css('li.dropdown-submenu a::attr(href)').getall()
```